# How can I get into debian to edit grub settings when grub is hidden and shift key does not bring up menu?

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I wanted to hide GRUB during boot, so that I can access the list of OS whenever I want to boot something other than the default. I hid GRUB by specifying in `/etc/default/grub` that

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

The problem is now that whenever I press the `shift` key duing boot, `Loading grub` is printed , but then quickly thereafter loads the OS without giving me an option to select OS.

Question

Now that I cannot get into grub using the `shift` key, how can I get into debian to change the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot your system from a [Debian installation disk](https://www.debian.org/CD/), choosing the [Rescue](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch08s07.html) option.

From there, you should be asked if you want to to open a shell on your original Debian file system, so you can edit `/etc/default/grub` file and then run `update-grub`.